# Well Ordering Principle confusion

Tags: discrete-mathematics, well-orders

I am very confused about how the well ordering principle works and was wondering if anyone could help me out. So if we have a non-empty set of integers $A$ and if there exists $b ∈ A$ such that for all $a ∈ A$, $b ≤ a$, then $b$ is the smallest element of $A$. The thing that confuses me is what $a$ is. Is $a$ any arbitrary integer greater than or equal to $b$ or is $a$ the integer that can come right after $b$, i.e. $b+1$? Also, how would we go about proving that $A$ even has a smallest element to begin with, given that $b\in\ \mathbb{Z}$?

Answer (score 1):

You said it yourself, $a$ is any member of $A$.  There is a big difference between the integers and the naturals in this respect.  The integers are not well ordered, so you can find subsets of the integers that do not have a smallest element.  One example would be all the even integers.  The naturals (whether you think they include $0$ or not) are well ordered, so any non-empty subset of the naturals has a smallest element.

Comment: So $a$ can be either $b$ or any other integer?

Comment: It can be $b$ or any other element of $A$.  You required, as is useful, that $a \in A$.  If $A$ is the set of positive even integers, $b$ is $2$ and $a$ can be any positive even integer.  The point is that $b$ is smaller than or equal to all the elements of $A$.  We are taking $a$ as a generic element of $A$.  The idea is that somebody gives us an $A$ and we are supposed to find the smallest element.  The statement that $\forall a\in A (b \le a)$ is what we mean by a smallest element.  You go through all the elements of $A$ and pick the smallest one.